# convert CAD to US dollar,

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a simple android app to convert CAD to US dollar, it's working but I'm always using the same rate so I'd like to get rates automatically from the internet, how can I do it?

this is my code :

```
public void currencyChange (View view){
    double usd = 0;
    String value;
    DecimalFormat finalUSD = new DecimalFormat("0.00");//To print just 2 decimals numbers
    Log.i("info","Button pressed");

    EditText cad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DollarEditText);
    value = cad.getText().toString();//Converting the value to string
    Log.i("amount in CAD ", cad.getText().toString());
    usd = Double.valueOf(value).doubleValue();

    usd = usd * 0.76; // ****  RATE   ****

    Log.i("amount in USD ", Double.toString(usd));




    Toast.makeText(this,value + " CAD" + " => " + finalUSD.format(usd) + " USD",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a source for this exchange rate, and do their terms give you the legal right to use it?

Comment: So many errors in this approach.  You should write a single function to do the conversion for you.  Take in a CAD value, return a USD amount.  Better yet, write something general that allows you to specify input and output currencies and the conversion strategy.  Never, ever mingle your view with a function this way.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+exchange+rates

Answer (score 0):

[Fixer](https://fixer.io/product) is a great option, with a free signup limiting you to 1,000 calls per month and fresh data every hour. When you sign up you will be given an access key, which you can then use in requests like this:

```
https://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=MY_ACCESS_KEY
```

The response will be in the following format:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1547937308,
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2019-01-19",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 4.177162,
        "AFN": 85.692162,
        ...
        "CAD": 1.507594,
        ...
        "USD": 1.137249,
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you have the exchange rate for CAD/EUR (EUR is the fixer base currency), and USD/EUR. By chaining these rates you can then obtain the desired CAD/USD rate.

```
usd_cad_rate = eur_cad_rate / eur_usd_rate
usd_cad_rate = 1.507594 / 1.137249 = 1.325649
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use daily fx exchange rates from the European Central Bank: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html

Please read the disclaimer, but they provide an PHP example on their website for developers. As far as I can see there are no other restrictions than naming them as source.

```
    String fxRates = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
    URLConnection httpcon = new URL(fxRates).openConnection();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db;
    try {
      db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse(httpcon.getInputStream());

      NodeList cubes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
      double fxEurCad = 0.0;
      double fxEurUsd = 0.0;

      for (int i = 0; i < cubes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node cube = cubes.item(i);
        Node currency = cube.getAttributes().getNamedItem("currency");
        Node rate = cube.getAttributes().getNamedItem("rate");
        if (null != currency && "CAD".equals(currency.getNodeValue())) {
          fxEurCad = Double.parseDouble(rate.getNodeValue());
        }
        if (null != currency && "USD".equals(currency.getNodeValue())) {
          fxEurUsd = Double.parseDouble(rate.getNodeValue());
        }
      }

      double fxCadUsd = fxEurCad/fxEurUsd;
```